# How to update Go dependencies

Tags: go, dependencies

the `go mod tidy` adds package dependencies to the go.mod file. How we can update them automatically without manually editing go.mod file, e.g. by removing some entries? For instance, if I use make I want to add a similar command that can update all dependencies of my package/repo and then compile the code with latest version of package dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to update all the dependencies you need to use:

```
go get -u
```

And then `go mod tidy`.

`go get -u` updates all packages and their dependencies, changing the `go.mod`.